# Loop through list of tupples and return matching tupple value in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have been struggling with this for hours,
I have a variable :

```
numbered_objects = [(index + 1, obj) for index, obj in enumerate(carts)]
```

that makes me a list like this from my Model :

```
[(1, <CalculatedNumbers: one>), (2, <CalculatedNumbers: two>), (3, <CalculatedNumbers: three>), (4, <CalculatedNumbers: four>), ...]
```

and I have another variable :
'usernobat'
that returns me a number

How can I go through my list of tupples, find the matching tupple index that is matching 'usernobat' and return its  data ?

I have tried for loops like this :

```
matching_object = None
    for obj in range(len(numbered_objects)):
        for key in numbered_objects[obj]:
            if key == usernobat:
                matching_object = key
                break
```

but they all return None

edit: I added my entire view :

```
def cart_resault(request):
    carts = CalculatedNumbers.objects.filter(used=False)[:50]
    usersubmit = UserSelection.objects.get(user=request.user)

    usernobat, usernobat__created = UserNobats.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

    numbers_sum = sum(getattr(usersubmit, f'number_{i}', 0) for i in range(1, 11))
    usernobat.usernobat = numbers_sum
    usernobat.save()
    
    
    numbered_objects = [(index + 1, obj) for index, obj in enumerate(carts)]
    
    matching_object = None
    for obj in range(len(numbered_objects)):
        for key in numbered_objects[obj]:
            if key == usernobat:
                matching_object = key
                break
```

Comment: Whhat is `usernobat` here?

Comment: Furthermore, what should be the `matching_object`? A `calculatedNumbers` object?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem usernobat is a user input number.
matching_object is the resault of the matching. for example if usernobat is 3 i want the matching 3 on CalculatedNumbers query that is generated with my numbered_objects

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I also included my entire view section for this

Comment: Can you share the model behind the `usernobat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `usernobat` is probably still a *string*, so `'2'` for example, not `2`, and thus `2 != '2'`.

You can cast it to a `2` with `int(…)` first, so:

```
usernobat = int(usernobat)

matching_object = None
for k, v in numbered_objects:
    if k == usernobat:
        matching_object = v
        break
```

Comment: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'UserNobats'

Comment: im the dumb one instead of comparing with usernobat.usernobat i was comparing with usernobat. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit: never mind, I don't see why your solution doesn't work.

Something like this should work:

```py
test = [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]

result = None
usernobat = 2

for element in test:
    if element[0] == usernobat:
        result = element
        break

print(result) # Gives (2, "b")
```

This will always give the first element found, which is the only element since `index + 1` will be unique.

If you want to get all results which match the key, you can use python's `filter`:

```py
result = list(filter(lambda element: element[0] == usernobat, test))
print(result) # Gives [(2, "b")]
```